# AVCaptureFileOutput returns a video rotated depending of the device's position

Tags: ios, swift, video, rotation, avfoundation

I'm recording a video using `AVFoundation` that can be captured in any landscape orientation (landscapeRight or landscapeLeft) for any selected camera (front/back).

By default, the input is rotated 90º and as a result, `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` looks like this:

[image]

But... not only `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, also the `AVCaptureFileOutput`, which is stored rotated.

To correct this issue, I firstly applied a correction in the `AVCaptureConnection` depending of the `UIDevice.current.orientation`, which displayed the video properly in the preview, but looking at the OutputFile, it keeps storing the same orientation with the difference of an exif extra param called `rotation` which points out the amouth of degrees that the video should be rotated to be displayed properly by a player:

[image]

That's great, but the problem comes when you want to include this video in your `AVComposition` for later being exported with `AVAssetExportSession`. The video result doesn't set any exif param, which means it has the correct orientation, but clips that compose the final result are rotated.

Is there any `swift` way to rotate the video in the `AVCaptureFileOutput` so I get the correct orientation without that rotation exif param?